# How to pair up Plantronics Backbeat 903 Stereo headset with Samsung R580 running Windows 7 32 bit

Tags: windows-7, windows, bluetooth

My Samsung has built in Bluetooth (Broadcom BCM2070 Bluetooth 3.0 USB Device - Driver Version:6.5.0.131). Bluetooth Remote control (Driver Versio: 6.3.0.6450) and Blurtooth Hands Free Audio (Driver Version: 6.3.0.7650).
According to the info.the Plantronics Backbeat 903 should work with PC or Laptop.
However my laptop cannot detect headset.
Anybody can help me out to fix this problem.
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the documentation on the Backbeat to find out how to get it to enter "pairing" or "discoverable" mode.  Then the PC should be able to pair with it.  You may need to enter a specific pairing code to allow the pairing to happen.  It will be in the documentation of the Backbeat.

Comment: I follow exactly the procedure stated in the user guide. Thanks for your reply.